# How do I create a date-formatted cell using RubyXL?

Tags: ruby, excel, openxml, rubyxl

I'm using RubyXL to dynamically generate a spreadsheet file that contains some dates. The documentation is kind of sparse so I've been looking at the source, and it appears the library only has special handling for `Date` and `DateTime` when you call `change_contents`, so that's what I'm doing:

```
cell = sheet.add_cell_obj RubyXL::Cell.new(sheet, row_index, col_index)
cell.change_contents(Time.now.to_datetime)
```

When I create a spreadsheet this way, Excel does not format those cells as dates. I'm guessing that I need to set some other field, perhaps `cell.datatype`, but I'm not sure. Or maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree. Does anybody know what to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See https://github.com/weshatheleopard/rubyXL/issues/210

```
c = workbook[0].add_cell(0,0)
c.set_number_format('m/d/yy')
c.change_contents(Date.today)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm still trying to figure out how to do this.

Comment: @RicardoJacas that work, but you should ensure, that you are inserting `Date` object into the cell. In my case there was `TimeWithTimezone` object, so it worked only if I call `c.change_contents(value.to_date)`

Comment: Thanks @GlebTarasov, it did work at the time checking the correct type.

Comment: It works, but you have to include (from version 3.4.0) [convenience methods](https://github.com/weshatheleopard/rubyXL#convenience-methods-)

Answer (score -3):

After finally forking the library and attempting to fix it myself, I've decided that RubyXL is a mess beyond repair. Fortunately, before descending completely into madness, I discovered **[Axlsx](https://github.com/randym/axlsx)**, a much better written, actively supported Ruby gem. **Ditch RubyXL and use Axlsx instead.**

Comment: I just inherited a project which used the `writeexcel` gem. This is primarily flawed in that it does not include READING of spreadsheets. So instead, I added the `spreadsheet` gem to do this. A little while later, I needed to upgrade things and do a gem clean-up, so replaced both of these tools with `rubyXL`. The library may be a mess, but at least it finally solves all my needs (including xlsx support) in one place. Unfortunately, Axlsx would not do this, due to its lack of support for READING spreadsheets. (And in addition, it contains loads of advanced features I simply do not need.)